# how to get metadata as a `0x${string}` type

Tags: polkadot-js

Hello guys i am trying to get the metadata as a `0x${string}` type. I am calling the api endpoint state_getMetadata with `await api.rpc.state.getMetadata()` however this returns an object of Metadata and i am trying to do offline singing of transctions.

I have followed the [github](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadot/src/polkadot.ts) examples where they are doing same thing however when i try to sign the transaction it wants the metadata to be of type `0x${string}` how do i properly convert or implement this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

In order to have the return value of `await api.rpc.state.getMetadata()` be a type of `0x${string}` all you need to do is call `.toHex()` on the return type.

So:

```
const metadata = await api.rpc.state.getMetadata();
const metadataHex = metadata.toHex();
```